# Subtract vectors, that contain duplicated elements

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates, set-intersection

Is there any elegant way to subtract `std::vector`s, that contain duplicated elements?

---

Example:

```
v1 = { 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2 }
v2 = { 2, 4, 3, 3, 3 }
result1 = ??( v1, v2 )
result2 = ??( v2, v1 )
```

and I want the result to be:

```
result1 = { 1, 1 }
result2 = { 4 }
```

---

My current (and very slow) solution:

```
1) sort v1 and v2
2) use std::unique_copy to v1_uniq, v2_uniq
3) intersect the new vectors with std::set_intersection
4) iterate over v1 and v2 and remove all elements, that are in the intersection 3)
```

My other idea is:

```
1) sort v1 and v2
2) iterate over v1 and v2 and remove duplicates in parallel
```

But this is kinda error-prone doesn't look elegant to me.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you always want to perform the operation two ways? (i.e. do you need both `result1` and `result2`?)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - yes, I do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with a unary predicate that checks whether the element is in the second vector. Or, if you don't have C++11 support, use [std::remove_copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) with the predicate's logic suitably changed.

For the unary predicate:

```
struct Foo {

  Foo(const std::vector& v) : v_(v) {}
  bool operator() (int i) const {
    // return true if i is in v_
  }
  const std::vector<int>& v_;

};
```

which can be instantiated like this:

```
Foo f(v2);
```

You could modify the functor to keep a sorted version of the reference vector, with unique entries to allow to do a binary search, but the general idea is the same.

Comment: And how this is supposed to work with unary predicates? To do what I want to do, I have to use binary predicate - one argument for the current element and one - for the other vector, right? (I will not make the other vector global variable..)

Comment: @KirilKirov I added an untested example. Obviously you could make the functor a template class.

Comment: Silly me! I totally forgot that functors can accept arguments in the constructor.. Thanks a lot! That works perfect.

Comment: @KirilKirov I added a sentence at the end, there is scope for optimization building on the same basic idea.

Answer (score 2):

I have a rather simple algorithm, which complexity is O(n²). However, it can be faster with a sort (O(n log n)). Here it is:

```
substract s from v
    for all elements of v
        for all elements of s
            if element i-th of v == element j-th of s
                then remove it from v and break the loop on s
```

With other structures, maybe it could be faster. For example, if elements were shared, you could detach all elements of v that are shared with s, with a O(n) complexity.

Comment: Yep, this is the trivial way, but it seems like it will be the best solution here. I'll wait for other ideas and if there aren't better, I'll accept your way. Thanks, +1 from me.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can get this down to O(n log n) by first sorting.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - yep, that was my second solution in the description of my question.

Comment: @KirilKirov Well, that clearly contradicts this answer which claims that you cannot make it less complex than O(n^2).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - whops, I read "you can", instead of "you cannot" :) I need a coffee. Of course you can - `2 * ni*log(ni)` for the sorting and `O(n)` for iterating over the sorted elements (where `n` is min( n1, n2) )